# shuffle array elements

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I found this code online for shuffling array elements, it works well, but I can't understand the `for` loop here

```
shuffle = function(o)
{ 
for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; 
    j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
return o;
};
```

any help is appreciated, thank you !

Comment: I think it's the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) with some unreadable coding style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a misuse of the flexibility of the `for` loop.

The general syntax for a `for` loop is:

```
for (<init>; <condition>; <increment>) {
  <body>
}
```

which roughly can be expressed as following `while` loop:

```
<init>;
while(<condition>) {
   <body>
   <increment>
}
```

Since both `<body>` and `<increment>` are both executed as if they were in the body of the `while`, anything that can go into the body of a `for` loop, can also be put in the `<increment>` expression of the `for` loop. You just have to separate the statements with commas instead of semicolons.

Thus your `for` loop is probably better expressed as following `while` loop:

```
var j, x, i = o.length; 
while (i) { // same as while(i != 0)
   j = parseInt(Math.random() * i);
   x = o[--i];
   o[i] = o[j];
   o[j] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
j = parseInt(Math.random() * i); // Getting a random number between 0 to n-1, where n is the length of the array.
x = o[--i]; // Getting the last element of the array and storing it in a variable.
o[i] = o[j]; // Storing the randomly selected index value at the last position.
o[j] = x; // Storing the last element's value in random position.
```

i value will decrement in each loop iteration and it will replace the last then next to last then so on... and finallly first element of the array with a random element within the aray.